# How can i open partial view in new window and call print method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

What im trying to do is when user click on ng-click to open new window and called print method in that new window that will be populated with partial view.Is that possible? I know that i can use $window.open() and $window.print() method but my problem is how to populate them with specific partial view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create print css for that. You can hide those divs's that you don't want to print.

For example :- you have two div's, let's suppose you don't want print the content of first div and you want to print only second div then the code would be like this -

```
**HTML page:-**

<div id="first-div">
  The content of first div
</div>

<div id="second-div">
  Content of second div
</div>

<!-- End HTML page -->

**Print CSS Page -** 

.first-div{
display:none;
```

}